# Javascript not executing when deployed to heroku, but works fine locally

Tags: javascript, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

This question seems to have been asked 30 different ways, and I've attempted all of the solves with no luck.

Rails 4 app that runs fine locally, but when deployed to heroku (Cedar), the javascript is not executing.  Process I'm going through:

1) RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
2) git add, then commit
3) git push heroku master

I've also tried clobbering the assets on both heroku and my local machine.

Production.rb

```
  config.cache_classes = true

  config.eager_load = true

  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  config.serve_static_assets = true

  config.assets.compress = true

  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

  config.assets.digest = true

  config.assets.precompile += %w( '.woff', '.eot', '.svg', '.ttf' )

  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new
```

application.rb

```
config.assets.version = '4.0'

config.assets.enabled = true

config.before_configuration do
  env_file = File.join(Rails.root, 'config', 'local_env.yml')
  YAML.load(File.open(env_file)).each do |key, value|
    ENV[key.to_s] = value
  end if File.exists?(env_file)
end

config.action_mailer.delivery_method   = :postmark
config.action_mailer.postmark_settings = { :api_key => ENV['POSTMARK_API_KEY']}

config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false

config.middleware.use Rack::Attack
```

I've also tried adding config.assets.compile = true

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require turbolinks
//= require masonry/jquery.masonry
//= require masonry/jquery.imagesloaded.min
//= require masonry/jquery.infinitescroll.min
//= require masonry/modernizr-transitions
//= require underscore
//= require gmaps/google
//= require_tree .
```

When I run the app on heroku, I can see the javascript in  through the developer tools:
[image]

..but the js is not executing.  Where am I going wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try moving `//=require Turbolinks` to the very bottom of your application.js and see if that doesn't help.  Also, you can try turning off turbolinks.  Turbolinks is cool, but doesn't always play nice with others.

Hope this helps!